# How to make Get request to Image API work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mvvm, uwp, dotnet-httpclient

I have no idea what the problem is, so I will just give you some context:

My Image Api GET method:

```
[Route("{name}", Name = "GetImageByName")]
    public IActionResult Get(string name)
    {
        string imagePath = GetImagePath();
        string fileName = $"{imagePath}\\{name}";

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
            return NotFound();

        try
        {
            var image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

            string extension = new FileInfo(fileName).Extension.Substring(1);
            return File(image, $"image/{extension}");
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (PathTooLongException ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(414, ex.Message);
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
        {
            return NotFound(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            return NotFound(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(415, ex.Message);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This works fine in postman:
GET request: https://localhost:44355/api/Images/Sheet1.png
This returns 200 OK and the Image

But with .net.http httpclient it is not working:

```
var uri = new Uri("https://localhost:44355/api/Images/Sheet1.png");
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri); //Not working and throws exception
```

I have also tried this to load images from my API:

```
public async Task<BitmapImage> GetImage(string imageStringName)
    {
        var uri = new Uri("https://picsum.photos/200/300");

        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        var rass = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(uri);
        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await rass.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
        }

        return bitmapImage;
    }
```

This works fine with an external dummy api, but not whit my localhost api.

So my final questions are: Why is not the last solution working for getting image from my API? Why is not a normal _httpClient.GetAsync(Uri) working? And what is the actual best solution for getting images from the api?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Message: "One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred while sending the request.)" string. System.Exception {System.AggregateException}. And InnerException: System.Exception {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException}

Comment: First off, I don't understand why you are getting an AggregateException. Are you not `await`ing throughout the entire call chain? Second, that is not helpful. The descriptive error is somewhere in the aggregate. You will want [to handle each exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=netframework-4.8) or flatten it to obtain what specifically happened. You probably just need to set the appropriate Accept header.

Answer (score 0):

UWP cannot access `localhost` by default. Check the "Loopback" section of [this MSDN document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/communication/interprocess-communication) for information on how to enable it.